# How do i extract URIs from multiple html documents?

Tags: web-applications

As the title already says, i want to scrape all the urls out of html files and convert this to plain text. Is there any tool (online for example) that allows to upload multiple files instead of one-per-one?

Comment: If you can do it for one you can do it for several in a loop if you have a programmable example. For example search for Python web scraping

Comment: @Wikunia does this also work for offline files?

Comment: You can read in your own html files yes. Read from file instead of getting it from the web